# PHP - Move files to another folder Except .php files

Tags: php

I would like to move all files EXCEPT .php files

The code below moves all files, I just don't know how to add for it to skip all .php files.

```
// Get array of all source files
$files = scandir("source");

// Identify directories
$source = "source/";
$destination = "destination/";

// Cycle through all source files
foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;

    // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
    if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
        $delete[] = $source.$file;
    }
}
// Delete all successfully-copied files
foreach ( $delete as $file ) {
    unlink( $file );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(substr($file, -4) != '.php') {
    if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
        $delete[] = $source.$file;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. However, after reading @Always Sunny's, I feel a combination of his and my answer would be the cleanest solution, using the `pathinfo` function (e.g. `$pathinfo = pathinfo($file); if($pathinfo['extension'] != 'php'){...}` Note that in this case, the file extension string should _not_ include the dot.

Comment: Hi, your answer was the fastest for me to implement and really simple.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a great function to help you capture only the files you need. Its called `glob()`,

glob - Find pathnames matching a pattern
Here is an example usage -

```
$phpfiles = array();
foreach (glob("/path/to/folder/*.php") as $file) {
  $files[] = $file;
}
$allfiles = scandir("/path/to/folder");
$files_that_are_not_php = array_diff($allfiles, $phpfiles); 
//move the files in $files_that_are_not_php array
```

Reference -

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I need the opposite, I need all the files except the *.php files to be moved.

Comment: @compcobalt, Answer edited + we can do provide guidance, but not always the exact answer. hope you get the idea. cheers

Comment: PHP is also great at providing functions whose name say nothing about what they actually do: `glob - Find pathnames matching a pattern`. Just sayin'...

Comment: Ha ha , Correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to exclude **.php** files inside your $files array looping.

**1st way**

```
$exclude=array('.php'); // add more extension if .
 foreach ( $files as $file ) {
 if(is_file($filepath)) {
      $ext = getFileExtension($filename);
      // execute code to list the file or whatever
        if (!in_array($ext,$exclude)) {
           // Code for files not .php file extension
         }
     }
   }


   function getFileExtension($filename) {
      $path_info = pathinfo($filename);
      return $path_info['extension'];
    }
```

**2nd way**

```
$files_without_php= preg_grep('~\.[^(php)]$~', 

 scandir($dir_f));
```